# Add right padding to string so that it displays in consistent row/column structure

Tags: javascript

## Update

From the look of things, it doesn't seem like I'm left with much options here expect using a monospace font as suggested by Andreas. However, given that the interface I'm using doesn't allow me control over fonts, I guess this would be undoable??

================================================================

I'm required to format a string to appear as a table. It will purely be text (not even RTF). The end result is that this will be populated in a textarea in a form. So far I've the following:

```
var content = [
    { columnName: 'Date of Birth:', value: '11/26/1994', 'editable':'N'},
    { columnName: 'Name:', value:  'Lewis Menelaws', 'editable':'Y'},
    { columnName: 'Address:', value:  '123 Apple Road', 'editable':'N'}
];


function padEnd(str){
    var size = 20;
    while(str.length < size){
        str += " ";
    }
    
    return str;
}

var str = "";
for(var key in content)
{
    var obj = content[key];
    str += padEnd(obj.columnName);
    str += padEnd(obj.value);
    str += obj.editable;
    str += "\n";
}
alert(str);
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Expectation is as follows:

[image]

Any suggestions?

**PS:** Strangely, if I `console.log(str)`, it appears well formatted in browser console. But I guess the format in which I'm seeing it in `alert` box is how it will get populated in the textarea.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsu76fwy/) for playing around

Comment: _"I'm required to format a string to appear as a table"_ - That's not a good idea (as you can see), because this will only ever work with a font whose characters all have the same width (monospace). Why not an actual table (or table-like structure), especially with that given input format?

Comment: Because the string has to go and sit inside a textarea. So I cannot use HTML tags.

Comment: Then use a monospaced font for the text area

Comment: And there's already `String.prototype.padEnd()`

Comment: not entirely relevant, but you could use the `.repeat` method for strings instead of looping to add spaces

Comment: @Andreas `String.prototype.padEnd()` is what I stumped upon at first but it doesn't have support in IE. So have to drop it.

Comment: _"...but it doesn't have support in IE"_ - IE? My condolences...

Comment: Could you use something other than a textarea? Like a table with input elements as cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best approach, but you can play around with measuring text width in a dynamically created invisible helper `div`. Then based on this, you can kind of calculate the required amount of spaces.

For example a simple `measureText` function could look like this.

```
function measureText(text) {
  var fontSize = 12;
  var test = document.getElementById("text-measure-helper");
  if (!test) {
    test = document.createElement("div");
    test.id = "text-measure-helper"
    test.style.position = "absolute";
    test.style.visibility = "hidden";
    test.style.width = "auto";
    test.style.height = "auto";
    test.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    document.body.appendChild(test);
  }

  test.innerHTML = text;
    test.style.fontSize = fontSize;

    return test.clientWidth + 1;
}
```

[Here is the modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p589x67e/).

Not perfect though in this form, still there is some slight mis-alignment, but maybe you can tweak it to get an acceptable end result.

Comment: This looks like the closest possible solution given the limitations I have.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given a thought about custom AlertBox through some of the framework you are using in your project, with inbuilt alert it seems not possible.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer (and OP is not asking for an alternative "alert")